# AWS Lambda thumbnail generator not working on larger file sizes

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, thumbnails

So I followed this tutorial by amazon:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html to make a thumbnail generator for every image that I upload to my S3 bucket.  It works fine on small images around 500KB, and it correctly puts them in the thumbnail bucket, but I attempted to upload a 300MB image file to my S3 bucket, and my lambda function doesn't seem to work correctly.

I looked through other forums and I have attempted to fiddle with some timeout and memory size settings in AWS Lambda becuase I thought that the function maybe needed more memory, but that wasn't the case and I personally don't know what else I have left to go off of.

Here is the copy of the lambda function straight from the link I used, the error occurs at line 57 when the MAX_HEIGHT and MAX_WIDTH are being set. It seems that size in the case of large files seems to always be undefined.

```
// dependencies
var async = require('async');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var gm = require('gm')
            .subClass({ imageMagick: true }); // Enable ImageMagick integration.
var util = require('util');

// constants
var MAX_WIDTH  = 100;
var MAX_HEIGHT = 100;

// get reference to S3 client 
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    // Read options from the event.
    console.log("Reading options from event:\n", util.inspect(event, {depth: 5}));
    var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    // Object key may have spaces or unicode non-ASCII characters.
    var srcKey    =
    decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));  
    var dstBucket = srcBucket + "resized";
    var dstKey    = "resized-" + srcKey;

    // Sanity check: validate that source and destination are different buckets.
    if (srcBucket == dstBucket) {
        callback("Source and destination buckets are the same.");
        return;
    }

    // Infer the image type.
    var typeMatch = srcKey.match(/\.([^.]*)$/);
    if (!typeMatch) {
        callback("Could not determine the image type.");
        return;
    }
    var imageType = typeMatch[1];
    if (imageType != "jpg" && imageType != "png") {
        callback('Unsupported image type: ${imageType}');
        return;
    }

    // Download the image from S3, transform, and upload to a different S3 bucket.
    async.waterfall([
        function download(next) {
            // Download the image from S3 into a buffer.
            s3.getObject({
                    Bucket: srcBucket,
                    Key: srcKey
                },
                next);
            },
        function transform(response, next) {
            gm(response.Body).size(function(err, size) {
                // Infer the scaling factor to avoid stretching the image unnaturally.
                var scalingFactor = Math.min(
                    MAX_WIDTH / size.width,
                    MAX_HEIGHT / size.height
                );
                var width  = scalingFactor * size.width;
                var height = scalingFactor * size.height;

                // Transform the image buffer in memory.
                this.resize(width, height)
                    .toBuffer(imageType, function(err, buffer) {
                        if (err) {
                            next(err);
                        } else {
                            next(null, response.ContentType, buffer);
                        }
                    });
            });
        },
        function upload(contentType, data, next) {
            // Stream the transformed image to a different S3 bucket.
            s3.putObject({
                    Bucket: dstBucket,
                    Key: dstKey,
                    Body: data,
                    ContentType: contentType
                },
                next);
            }
        ], function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(
                    'Unable to resize ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
                    ' and upload to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey +
                    ' due to an error: ' + err
                );
            } else {
                console.log(
                    'Successfully resized ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
                    ' and uploaded to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey
                );
            }

            callback(null, "message");
        }
    );
};
```

Here is the error message directly from AAWS Cloud Watch logs:

```
2019-05-14T22:31:28.731Z    b5fccf54-e55f-49f2-9206-462fa5769149    TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined
at gm.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:57:38)
at emitMany (events.js:147:13)
at gm.emit (events.js:224:7)
at gm.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/gm/lib/getters.js:70:16)
at cb (/var/task/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:322:16)
at gm._spawn (/var/task/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:226:14)
at gm._exec (/var/task/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:190:17)
at gm.proto.(anonymous function) [as size] (/var/task/node_modules/gm/lib/getters.js:68:12)
at transform (/var/task/index.js:54:31)
at nextTask (/var/task/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5324:14)
```

EDIT: In addition I also seem to get this error which alternated between the two:

```
2019-05-14T22:55:25.923Z    7a7f1ec2-cd78-4fa5-a296-fee58033aea6    Unable to resize MYBUCKET/image.png and upload to MYBUCKETRESIZE/resize-image.png due to an error: Error: Stream yields empty buffer
```

EDIT: Added the report line:

```
REPORT RequestId: a67e1e79-ebec-4b17-9832-4049ff31bd89  Duration: 7164.64 ms    Billed Duration: 7200 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB   Max Memory Used: 810 MB
```

Comment: Can you post the REPORT line at the end of the cloudwatch log? Just to make sure you're not still using all the memory. Depending on a few factors, you could end up using even 6x your memory by passing it around between promises, before GC kicks in. e.g., `REPORT RequestId: d94ac5ee-a088-11e8-8227-c39cd22f11a8 Duration: 13.44 ms Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 87 MB`. And have you tried file sizes inbetween? 50MB, 150MB

Comment: The other small possibility is that the gm/imagemagick module is writing to disk for larger files. I don't know anything about the library. There's a 512MB restriction on /tmp. Though afaik this would cause a 'no space left on device' error

Comment: @jameslol i just edited in the report like from the clloudwatch log, it doesn't seem that it is using all of its memory.  This last file that I uploaded was 180MB and the same errors are appearing.

Comment: I'm not sure how perfectly accurate the log is there. For shits and giggles I would set the lambda to 3GB memory and run the 180MB file again. Also - i know it's a long shot - check for disk space usage. (I'll put it in a placeholder answer to this question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two errors are for slightly different reasons.

`Stream yields empty buffer` almost definitely means you're running out of memory.

The other error might be a specific imagemagick error, which I don't think you're handling. Though it is also probably related to the memory issue. Because it's in a callback, you need to check the `err` variable:

```
function transform(response, next) {
    gm(response.Body).size(function(err, size) {
        if (err) throw err;
```

---

The imagemamgick module might be writing something to /tmp. A snippet for checking/clearing disk usage from a project i worked on

```
const fs = require('fs')
const folder = '/tmp/'

// Deleting any files in the /tmp folder (lambda will reuse the same container, we will run out of space)
const files = fs.readdirSync(folder)
for (const file of files) {
  console.log('Deleting file from previous invocation: ' + folder + file)
  fs.unlinkSync(folder + file)
}
```

Comment: So when I set the memory value for the lambda function to 3BG, the 180MB file ran just fine! Should I Still implement this disk usage snippit within the lambda function to clear disk usage after each run?

Comment: It's probably not necessary if nothing is being written to /tmp. Running the function one time should tell you - if it doesn't log to console 'Deleting file...' then there's nothing in there and you don't need it. Note that i've also updated my answer relating to the first error message you were getting. Hope it helps